# high-level IPC library needed

Tags: ipc, dbus

Suppose that we have four process A, B, C, and D.  Usually, B-D send packets to A and get a reply from A.  (The packet represents a simple command, so it is very small)  However, sometimes, 'A' broadcasts an event, so that all of B-D should be notified.

At first glance, My mind came up with 'dbus'.  Unfortunately, we need a open source library that is not GPLed. (LGPL or BSD should be nice)

Is there any good library to recommend to me?

The target will be various linux devices (kernel 2.6.x and glibc 2.8.x) without X window system.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using any of the already built in IPC in linux?  Such as pipes or msq queues?  You could easily write wrappers to send and receive your custom packet types.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the D-Bus daemon and reference client-side implementation is [dual licensed](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/tree/COPYING), with the [AFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_Free_License) version 2.1 offered as an alternative to the GPL. So perhaps it is suitable for your uses after all.